# Watermark on empeded image wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, image, watermark

In my personal website I want to add image from my one drive to site as empeded image ,but I want to add watermark on all images , uploaded image can add watermark now , but I don't know how to add to empeded image,

Comment: So you would get the image from WP... then do the above with it, and use the result.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use a plugin that handles this already. There is alot that would go into coding a feature like this for yourself. There are many plugins that handle this. If you wanted to code it yourself, I would still suggest looking at the existing plugins, to see what features they offer and what problems they have solved already.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/watermark/

Comment: This is defo easiest way.  Take plugin apart to see how they do it.... looks like a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51489082/watermark-on-empeded-image-wordpress